# How to handle internet connection drops?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

My app downloads data from web and shows it to user. To prevent app crashes caused by absence of internet connection I've implemeted function which checks if there is one before download is started.  I don't know how to handle cases when connection drops while download is processing (in AsyncTask). `Catch`ing Exepctions doesn't work in my case :(
If there is any ideas or links to tutorials, please share with it.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this will help out. Whatever activity you have performing the download should create a BroadcastReceiver that can handle connectivity status notifications. Then you will be notified the connection has dropped and can handle it more gracefully... like waiting for notification that connectivity is back and restarting the download:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mConnReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        boolean missingConnection = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
        String reason = intent.getStringExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_REASON);

        // do whatever you need to based on current network state
    }
```

This page has good info as well: http://thiranjith.com/2011/03/31/how-to-monitor-network-connectivity-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

You can check for connection drops periodically outside of `AsyncTask` or in another thread. Then if the connection drops you can cancel the AsyncTask by calling `cancel()`.